# Map / Merge two object based on Key vs Value in DW 2.0

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I'm looking for a solution to Merge or so called Map or Combine an Object into another object based on the Value in Object A vs Key in Object B. For example:

Variable:

```json
    {
       "Column 1": "First Name",
       "Column 2": "Last Name",
       "Column 3": "ID",
       "Column 4": "Contact"
    }
```

Payload:

```json
    {
       "ID": "1234",
       "First Name": "Tom",
       "Last Name": "Jerry"
    }
```

Expected Output:

```json
    {
       "Column 1": "Tom",
       "Column 2": "Jerry",
       "Column 3": "1234",
       "Column 4": ""
    }
```

Refer to the example above, i'm using a variable as my "Template" and i would like to map my payload into it as shown in the example output. If the field is not found (e.g Column 4: Contact) then it can default as "" or null.

I'm not sure is this possible in DW as I had search for different map/mapObject solutions but still not works for me. Any solution and suggestion are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can easily be achieved using [mapObject()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-mapobject) and reference each key using the [dynamic selector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-selectors#dynamic_selector):

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var referenceVar={
   "Column 1": "First Name",
   "Column 2": "Last Name",
   "Column 3": "ID",
   "Column 4": "Contact"
}
---
referenceVar mapObject ((value, key, index) -> (key): payload[value])
```

"Column 4" will output null because it has no value by that key in the payload. If you prefer to output an empty string ("") you can use a default:

```js
referenceVar mapObject ((value, key, index) -> (key): payload[value] default "")
```

Comment: Thanks! This is so simple, why I dint think on this earlier...